# SQLite connection strategies

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, nhibernate, connection-string

I have a database that may be on the network drive. 
There are two things that I want to achieve:

1. When the first user connects to it in read-only mode (he doesn't
   have a read-write access to the location, or the database is
   read-only), other users must use the read-only connection also (even
   if they have RW access).
2. When the first user connects to it in RW mode, others can not
   connect to the database at   all.

I'm using SQLite, and the concurrency should not be the problem, as the database should never be used by more than 10 people at the same time.

**UPDATE:** This is a sample that I'm trying to make work, so I could implement it in the program itself. Almost everything can be changed.

**UPDATE:** Now when I finally understood what @CL. was telling me, I made it work and this is the updated code.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using DbSample.Domain;
using DbSample.Infrastructure;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using NHibernate.Util;


namespace DbSample.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDatabaseContext databaseContext = null;

            databaseContext = new SqliteDatabaseContext(args[1]);

        var connection = LockDB(args[1]);
        if (connection == null) return;

        var sessionFactory = databaseContext.CreateSessionFactory();
        if (sessionFactory != null)
        {

            int insertCount = 0;

            while (true) 
            {

                try
                {

                    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(connection))
                    {
                        string result;
                        session.FlushMode = NHibernate.FlushMode.Never;

                        var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand();

                        command.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction(ReadCommited))
                        {
                            bool update = false;
                            bool delete = false;
                            bool read = false;
                            bool readall = false;
                            int op = 0;
                            System.Console.Write("\nMenu of the day:\n1: update\n2: delete\n3: read\n4: read all\n0: EXIT\n\nYour choice: ");
                            op = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());
                            if (op == 1)
                                update = true;
                            else if (op == 2)
                                delete = true;
                            else if (op == 3)
                                read = true;
                            else if (op == 4)
                                readall = true;
                            else if (op == 0)
                                break;
                            else System.Console.WriteLine("Are you retarded? Can't you read?");




                            if (delete)
                            {
                                System.Console.Write("Enter the ID of the object to delete: ");
                                var objectToRemove = session.Get<MyObject>(System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine()));

                                if (!(objectToRemove == null))
                                {
                                    session.Delete(objectToRemove);
                                    System.Console.WriteLine("Deleted {0}, ID: {1}", objectToRemove.MyName, objectToRemove.Id);
                                    deleteCount++;
                                }
                                else
                                    System.Console.WriteLine("\nObject not present in the database!\n");


                            }

                            else if (update)
                            {
                                System.Console.Write("How many objects to add/update? ");
                                int number = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());
                                number += insertCount;
                                for (; insertCount < number; insertCount++)
                                {

                                    var myObject = session.Get<MyObject>(insertCount + 1);

                                    if (myObject == null)
                                    {
                                        myObject = new MyObject
                                            {
                                                MtName = "Object" + insertCount,
                                                IdLegacy = 0,
                                                                                           };
                                        session.Save(myObject);
                                        System.Console.WriteLine("Added {0}, ID: {1}", myObject.MyName, myObject.Id);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        session.Update(myObject);
                                        System.Console.WriteLine("Updated {0}, ID: {1}", myObject.MyName, myObject.Id);
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            else if (read)
                            {

                                System.Console.Write("Enter the ID of the object to read: ");
                                var objectToRead = session.Get<MyObject>(System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine()));
                                if (!(objectToRead == null))
                                    System.Console.WriteLine("Got {0}, ID: {1}", objectToRead.MyName, objectToRead.Id);
                                else
                                    System.Console.WriteLine("\nObject not present in the database!\n");

                            }

                            else if (readall)
                            {

                                System.Console.Write("How many objects to read? ");
                                int number = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());
                                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                                {
                                    var objectToRead = session.Get<MyObject>(i + 1);
                                    if (!(objectToRead == null))
                                        System.Console.WriteLine("Got {0}, ID: {1}", objectToRead.MyName, objectToRead.Id);
                                    else
                                        System.Console.WriteLine("\nObject not present in the database! ID: {0}\n", i + 1);


                                }

                            }
                            update = false;
                            delete = false;
                            read = false;
                            readall = false;

                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                    }    
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }


            }
            sessionFactory.Close();
        }

    }

    private static SQLiteConnection LockDbNew(string database)
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(database);
        if (!fi.Exists)
            return null;
        var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder { DefaultTimeout = 1, DataSource = fi.FullName, Version = 3 };

        var connectionStr = builder.ToString();
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionStr) { DefaultTimeout = 1 };
        var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection);

        connection.Open();

        // try to get an exclusive lock on the database
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE; BEGIN EXCLUSIVE; COMMIT;";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        // if we can't get the exclusive lock, it could mean 3 things
        // 1: someone else has locked the database
        // 2: we don't have a write acces to the database location
        // 3: database itself is a read-only file
        // So, we try to connect as read-only
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // we try to set the SHARED lock
            try
            {
                // first we clear the locks
                cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyObject";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // then set the SHARED lock on the database
                cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyObject";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                readOnly = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // if we can't set EXCLUSIVE nor SHARED lock, someone else has opened the DB in read-write mode and we can't connect at all
                connection.Close();
                return null;
            }

        } 
        return connection;
    }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode) to prevent SQLite from releasing its locks after a transaction ends.

Comment: Yes, that'll solve the second part, but what about the first one? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This is so close to the solution, but I have a problem with this. If I set it to EXCLUSIVE, the SHARED lock is obtained after the first read, and that is great as all users will be able to read it. But if I try to write, after a few reads, I get the "database is locked" exception, because the SHARED lock is held on the database, even if it's still the same user. I do Transaction.Commit() after every operation, and Session.FlushMode=Commit.

Comment: So a read lock prevents writes; isn't that what you wanted? If you want to get the exception at the beginning of the write transaction, execute [BEGIN IMMEDIATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: Completely true, but if I'm the first user of the DB, and I have RW access and I want to use it. With EXCLUSIVE lock, I'll block all other users from connecting, which is great. But I myself can't start new transactions, because I have an connection error. I open a new session using(var session=sessionFactory.OpenSession()) and it has connection error (locked DB). So I'm asking what should be the scope of the session, and what PRAGMAs or other parameters should I use to accomplish my goals. I am somehow wrong, and I can't see how.

Comment: Reuse the existing session.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be done within db but in application; 
You can set a global variable (not sure if it's a web or desktop app) to check if anyone connected and he has a write access or not.
After that you can check the other client's state.

Comment: It's a desktop application, I apologize for not stating that.