# SQLite - Open an EXCLUSIVE connection, fallback to SHARED on failure

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection, connection-string

I'm trying to create a 'fallback' mechanism, which will allow a process to gain EXCLUSIVE lock on a db file, and if it fails - gain a SHARED [=readonly] lock.

The idea is that once a process gains an EXCLUSIVE lock, it will write some information about itself in one of the tabels, so once another process tries to gain an EXCLUSIVE lock - it will fail, but will be able to perform 'SELECT' queries on the db.

I found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775418/sqlite-connection-strategies) question, which only describes half the answer - i'm able to gain 'EXCLUSIVE' lock, but I didn't find a way to gain a 'SHARED' lock.

Pseudo code:

```
try
{
  OpenExclusive();
  // Perform INSERT/UPDATE statements
}
catch(ExclusiveConnectionException)
{
  OpenShared();
  // Perform SELECT statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working simply by using transactions, but first make sure you set the connection string's 'DefaultTimeout' value to '0':

```
connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=...;Version=3;DefaultTimeout=0"
```

This will prevent the 'connection.Open' statement from hanging.

```
connection.Open(); // Opens connection as SHARED
try
{
    // Gain exclusive write-lock by beginning a transaction:
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN IMMEDIATE";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch(SQLiteException ex)
{
    if (ex.ResultCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Busy)
    {
        // Connection is still open as read-only (can perform SELECT statements)
    }
    else
        // Unexpected exception:
        throw;
}
```

In order for the data to remain synced, we must COMMIT and RESTART the transaction after each writing operation:

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    // Notice the 'COMMIT; BEGIN IMMEDIATE;' statements in the end:
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SOME_TABLE] VALUES('foo','bar'); COMMIT; BEGIN IMMEDIATE;";
}
```